# How to update component correctly?(react+flux)

Tags: reactjs, flux, reactjs-flux

I'm using ReactJs + flux. In my store I have a method - `getCurrentEvents(key)`.It recieves key and creates array of objects correctly. After that it emitts change.
I have component-list, which has handler. This handler answers to store change and calls method `displayEvents()`. This method updates component's state. This conception works but not correctly. When I call `getCurrentEvents(key)` it begins updating `EventList-component` and doesn't stop, as a result tab in browser freezes.As I understand I got something like limitless cycle of updates, I think that something wrong is in component's methods, but I can't understand where is the mistake. How to fix this bug?

store code:

```
class EventStore extends EventEmitter {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.events = [{
        id: 1,
        title: 'title 1',
        date: '2017-04-11 09:14:01'
        }, {
        id: 2,
        title: 'title 2',
        date: '2017-04-11 09:24:01'
        }, {
        id: 3,
        title: 'title 3',
        date: '2017-04-12 09:14:01'
        }, {
        id: 4,
        title: 'title 4',
        date: '2017-11-12 19:14:01'
        }, {
        id: 5,
        title: 'title 5',
        date: '2017-06-13 19:00:01'
        }
    ];
  }

  getCurrentEvents(key) {
    var currentEvents = [];
    for (event in this.events){
        if (this.events[event].date.includes(key)) {
            currentEvents.push(this.events[event]);
        }
    }

    return currentEvents;
    this.emit("change");
  }

  createEvent(new_event) {
    this.events.push ({
        title: new_event.title,
        date: new_event.date
    })
    this.emit("change");
  }

  getAll() {
    return this.events
  }


  handleActions(action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'CREATE_EVENT' : {
        this.createEvent(action.new_event);
      }
        case 'DISPLAY_CURRENT_EVENTS' : {
        this.getCurrentEvents(action.key);
      }
    }
  }
}

const eventStore = new EventStore;

dispatcher.register(eventStore.handleActions.bind(eventStore))

export default eventStore;
```

EventList component code:

```
export default class EventList extends React.Component {

      constructor () {
        super();
        this.state = {
            events: EventStore.getCurrentEvents()
        };
        this.displayEvents = this.displayEvents.bind(this);
      }

      componentWillMount() {
        EventStore.on("change", this.displayEvents)
      }

      displayEvents() {

        this.setState ({
                events: EventStore.getCurrentEvents()
        })
      }

      render() {
        console.log('form events LIST', this.state)

        const events = this.state.events ;
        var EventsList = [];

        for (event in events) {
            EventsList.push(
             <li key={events[event].id} id={events[event].id}>
                {events[event].title} , {events[event].date}
             </li>
             )
        }
        return (
        <div className="">
          <h3> Events on this day </h3>

          <ul className="event-list-wrapper">
             {EventsList}
          </ul>
        </div>
        );
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like it's because the `getCurrentEvents(key)` function is emitting a 'change' which is triggering `displayEvents`...which calls `getCurrentEvents(key)`...which emits a 'change' event which calls `displayEvents`...

Comment: thank you very much for this hint. i've rearranged some methods and now it works)